# fvwm, gtk and xombrero: input fields are white text on white background

Tags: gtk, fvwm

I have just started using `fvwm` window manager, and I am using `xombrero` browser on OpenBSD. 
(**update** this is `gtk` issue not window manager)

However, the color of the address bar, search box, and command box are all white (or off-white) text and white (or off-white) background. Highlighting the text also is white. So it's impossible to read the input text.

Input forms within the page are colored fine, although highlighting causes white on white.

I looked through the xombrero man pages but found no reference to any way of changing the color of any of those items. Therefore I thought this is maybe controlled by `fvwm` through some `FvwmForm` parameter.

I tried adding `*FvwmFormBack Black` to my `.fvwmrc` file and reloading `fvwm`, but it didn't seem to fix anything.

Anybody know what and where is the control parameter for the (a) background and text color of (web browser) input fields, and (b) the highlighting color for `fvwm`?

(Or if this is absolutely not a `fvwm` issue, please let me know, but I would pretty surprised if the creators of `xombrero` would make white on white text be default and not configurable).

This is a gtk3 issue I didn't have a gtk3 theme installed. Gtk3 is used to control the relevant input fields. To fix it, I installed a theme into `~/.themes/THEME_NAME` folder, and added the following to /etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:

```
［Settings]
gtk-theme-name = THEME_NAME
```

But that is only for one user. How can I install the system default gtk3 theme?

I searched for relevant `man` pages but came up dry for good gtk3 reference.

Answer (score 2):

Gtk3 is used to control the relevant input fields in xombrero and some other gui unix apps.

In this case, I was missing a gtk3 theme, and the default text color apparently was white.

To fix it:

**Option 1: gtk theme**

1. Download (lightweight) gtk3 theme (if you dont have one already)
2. extract it into~/.themes/THEME_NAME folder
3. added the following to /etc/gtk-3.0/settings.ini:

   ［Settings]
   gtk-theme-name = THEME_NAME

**Note** this fixes the issue for a single user, but is not very good solution, because the system settings file points to a theme that is not installed for all users. I hope sonebody else has a way to install for entire system.

**Option 2: change the xombrero gtk file**

(Thanks to xombrero mailing list)

In the file `/usr/local/share/xombrero/xombrero.css`, change the following

old:

```
.entry { padding: 2px; color:@text_color; }
```

new:

```
.entry {padding: 2px; color: black;}
```

This method might cause issues if a dark background for gtk theme is used though.

Comment: Just editing the css file helped me, for getting started.

Comment: `/usr/share/xombrero/xombrero.css` on Debian Jessie